# Creating a unique ID for every item within an array, even if called more than once on a page

Tags: php, html

On a website I am creating, I have the store 'open hours' in three locations on one page. One in the header, one in the body and one in the footer. I am trying to pull these in with PHP for simplicity when updating. I wrote an array:

```
<?php
$UniqID = uniqid(day);
$day1 = 'Mon-Fri: 9:00a-5:00p';
$day2 = 'Saturday: 9:00a-1:00p';
$day3 = 'Sunday: CLOSED';
$days = array(
    "1" => "<span id=" . $UniqID . " class='editable-text'>" . $day1 . "</span>",
    "2" => "<span id=" . $UniqID . " class='editable-text'>" . $day2 . "</span>",
    "3" => "<span id=" . $UniqID . " class='editable-text'>" . $day3 . "</span>",<
);
?>
```

and then am calling it on the page as such:

```
<span>Address | Phone <br/> Our Hours: <?php echo $days[1] ?>, <?php echo $days[2] ?>, <?php echo $days[3] ?></span>
```

The problem I have is that I need a unique ID EVERY time these are called to the page, and obviously this gives a unique ID for 1, 2 and 3 - but if I call that same thing on the page 2 or 3 times... well, then all three of the first instances have the same ID and so on.

**So to sum it all up, I want to create an array that stores the hours like above - and be able to call them to the page however many times necessary but always get a unique ID wherever they show up.**

Any help is appreciated, I can't process this anymore!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is declare the unique ID at the very top, like you have with `$uniqueID=X`

Then, every time you insert `$uniqueID` into the DOM, increment it as well.  So:

`<?php echo "<span id='".$uniqueID++."'>STUFF IN SPAN</span>"; ?>`

If `$uniqueID` is an int, the "++" will increment it, thus maintaining a unique one for each time it's inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring one unique ID at the top, declare it once for every `<span>`. It is also possible to declare it in a loop with a variable variable, like this:

```
$day1 = 'Mon-Fri: 9:00a-5:00p';
$day2 = 'Saturday: 9:00a-1:00p';
$day3 = 'Sunday: CLOSED';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $days[$i] = "<span id='uid" . uniqid() . "' class='editable-text'>" . ${'day'.$i} . "</span>";
}
```

This will produce something like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => <span id='uid53350c2f730eb' class='editable-text'>Mon-Fri: 9:00a-5:00p</span>
    [2] => <span id='uid53350c2f73156' class='editable-text'>Saturday: 9:00a-1:00p</span>
    [3] => <span id='uid53350c2f731d0' class='editable-text'>Sunday: CLOSED</span>
)
```

Note that the `id` attribute [cannot start with a number](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/) (or else it's not valid HTML), so you should probably put some letters before the uniqid() like I did (with `uid`). Also, you were missing quotes around the `id` value.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work... although I combined a few of your guys responses and did get a unique ID in every situation. I need a unique ID for a content editor tool I am integrating which is being a real pain. FYI, I had letters in front of my ID... I defined it at the top as uniqid(day); so day would print in front. But you're right, I forgot the quotes...